# Angularjs: loading new page with anchor

Tags: angularjs, scope, anchor, loading

I have a problem with anchors in angularjs.
I want to show some section on my page () AFTER my page is loaded (http://someurl.com/#/mypage#myanchor) 
I have directive which I am using on that page:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function ($location, $window, $rootScope, $anchorScroll) {

    return {        
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'views/mytemplate.html',
        scope: {
            type: '@',
            data :'='
        },
        link: function (scope) {
           scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
            if($location.hash()) {
               $anchorScroll();
             }
          }
        scope.$watch('data', function () {
               scope.scrollTo();               

            }, true);
  }
```

}

**but seems that it's trying to scroll to the anchor BEFORE page is completely loaded**. 
When I am putting button on page and calling scrollTo() it's working, but I need without any click, when the page is loaded.
I have noticed the exact question was asked before with no answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092748/external-anchor-links-in-angularjs

Comment: You could wrap the $watch function in a $timeout with a 0ms delay. This would queue the function to the end of the dom loading process.

Comment: Thank you , I used your advise and called $anchoreScroll in $timeout.                 $timeout(function() {
            $anchorScroll();
            }, 0);